# Eclipse Wizard does not close on "finish" in a production environment

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse plugin which runs fine in the eclipse version i'm using for developing it. It basicly also runs fine if i export it and install it in a fresh keppler version.

My plugin contains a New Project wizard to create projects which can be used with the plugin.

Now if i used this wizard in my development eclipse if i click `finish`, everything runs fine the project is created and the dialog is closed.

If i do the same in the fresh keppler installation, the project will also be created and everthing seems to be correct but the dialog won't close until i hit `cancel`.

Now i really wanted to come up with more information but in the development environment there is no exception occuring.

Also when i start the fresh keppler one with the `-debug` option i won't get an exception if i hit finish().

Any ideas what could cause this problem or how i could get more information on this?

Comment: Check the `.log` file in the workspace `.metadata` directory to see if any error has been logged.

Comment: Thank you! There's been an pretty obvious NullPointerException there indicating that i forgot to add a resource to the binary build options in the MANIFEST. Lesson learned: Errors won't display on the console even with -debug. Thanks! Feel free to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always worth looking in the `.log` file in the workspace `.metadata` directory when something unexplained happens to see if something has been logged.

In fact it is worth checking the log once in a while during plug-in development just in case something has been logged.